# php image open using session user name as "username".jpg

Tags: php

this is my first time asking a question about this but unlike my other problems i have been unable to find the specific answer i am seeking.  i am very new to php but it's working well on a current project.

i have this line of code which works perfectly in context of my page when the image file name  is set to a specific name.

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['userName'];?>

<?php echo "<img src='videos/jpgs/'userName'.jpg' width='83'
 height='20'/>"; ?>!
```

what i would like to do is open an image which uses the user name as the image filename.  The images are in the folder in the path.  The users are set internally and their user names are predetermined.

thanks in advance.

Comment: String interpolation is covered early on in the PHP manual. You should read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
<?php echo "<img src='videos/jpgs/".$_SESSION['userName'].".jpg' width='83' height='20'/>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src='videos/jpgs/<?php echo $_SESSION['userName']; ?>.jpg'/>
```

You could try this one too